# SQL Server: UPDATE based on whether a value is greater or lesser than another value, in a single query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking to update SQL Server in a single query based on a date, however the value updated depends on whether it is greater or lower than a provided value (in this scenario a date).

```
UPDATE table 
SET id = 'over'
WHERE date > '2022-01-01'

UPDATE table
SET id = 'under'
WHERE date < '2022-01-01'
```

I can do this individually via the queries above. My question is, is there a way in SQL Server to combine these two queries and run this update in a  single update query?

EDIT: to show the SET values are strings.

Comment: Use `CASE` expression.

Comment: `CASE` or `IIF` should work here

Comment: What are `over` and `under` - column names? Variables? Strings missing delimiters? Something else? What do you want to happen when `date = '20220101'`?

Comment: strings sorry, amended my question

Comment: And what about the boundary value? What should `id` be set to for values on Jan 1?

Comment: id is just the column name (probably a bad choice of name) all data will have a date assigned to it in the db. I want to update an additional column (id) with either over or under based on a date I provide the query.

Comment: Yes, I understand the requirement, but you didn't explain what you want to happen when `date = '20220101'` (or `date IS NULL`) - only what happens if it's before that or after that. If it's not possible for the data to have a row for that date, you should still include it in one range (using `>=` or `<=` in one of the expressions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
UPDATE table 
SET id = case 
   when (date > '2022-01-01') then over
   when (date < '2022-01-01') then under
   end;
```

Comment: Don't forget 2022-01-01, and NULL.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `CASE` expression to evaluate all possible conditions and return the appropriate values for each condition. Note, that if you omit the `ELSE` part of the `CASE` and no condition evaluates to `TRUE`, the result is `NULL`.

```
UPDATE [table]
SET [id] = CASE 
              WHEN [date] > '20220101' THEN 'over'
              WHEN [date] < '20220101' THEN 'under'
              ELSE ''
           END
```

Comment: Don't forget 2022-01-01, and NULL.